# ftpwebrequest with progress bar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, where users should be able to upload large files (2-3 GB). To upload the files, I make use of the ftpWebRequest class. 
Right now, I've a small jQuery script that makes an Ajax call, sends the complete path to the server, and from there the controller uploads the file to an external ftp server.

I want to add a progress bar. Below you can find what I've got so far:

- On button click the modal opens;
- uploading starts (even when I close my IE, it continues);
- the process bar is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "File Upload";
}

<div class="row">
    <h2>File upload</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group noleftpadding">
                <input type="button" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>

</div>

@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp;
    myApp = myApp || (function () {

        var modal = '';
        modal += '<div class="modal" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">';
        modal += '<div class="modal-dialog">';
        modal += '<div class="modal-content">';
        modal += '<div class="modal-header"><h1>Processing...</h1></div>';
        modal += '<div class="modal-body"><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>';
        modal += '</div></div></div>';
        var pleaseWaitDiv = $(modal);
        return {
            showPleaseWait: function () {
                pleaseWaitDiv.modal();
            },
            hidePleaseWait: function () {
                pleaseWaitDiv.modal('hide');
            },

        };
    })();

    $(function () {

        $(":button").on("click", function () {

            uploadFile();
        });


        function uploadFile() {
            myApp.showPleaseWait();
            var file = $('#file').val();
            alert(file);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "/Upload/AjaxUploadFile/");
            ajax.send(formData);
        }

        function progressHandler(event) {
            var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
            $('.bar').width(percent);
        }

        function completeHandler() {
            myApp.hidePleaseWait();
            $('.bar').width(100);
        }
    });
</script>


}
```

**UploadController**

```
public ActionResult AjaxUploadFile(string file)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> strMsg = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            completePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(file);
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(completePath);

            string strFtp = "ftp://" + serverIp + "/folder/" + fileName;

            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strFtp);
                ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
                ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

                byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(completePath);
                ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;
                using (Stream s = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                }

                FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();
                if (ftpResp != null)
                {
                    strMsg.Add("fileUpload", "Success!");
                }
                else {
                    strMsg.Add("fileUpload", "No file uploaded!");
                }

                return Json(strMsg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strMsg.Add("fileUpload", "Server Error!");
                return Json(strMsg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }


        }
```